# Erlang: calling rr(?MODULE) from beam executable?

Tags: function, erlang, initialization, record

I'm not entirely sure how to define an Erlang function within an Erlang module. I'm getting the following error:

```
11> invoke_record:invoke().
** exception error: undefined function erlang:rr/1
```

From this simple code trying to invoke the `rr(?MODULE).` from within the beam executable in order to "initialize" records so that it doesn't need to be called from the shell every time.

```
-module(invoke_record).
-export([invoke/0]).
-record(process, {pid,
                reference="",
                lifetime=0
                }).
invoke() ->
    erlang:rr(?MODULE).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command `rr("file.hrl").` is meant to be be used only in shell for debugging purposes.

As other users highlighted in their answers, the correct way to import a record (or a function) contained in a .hrl file within your erlang code consists in using the command `-include("file.hrl')`.

Once you have included the `.hrl` file in your code (and usually in a module based on OTP behaviours this is done after the `-export(...)` part) you can refer to the Erlang record (or function) without any problem.

Comment: "once you have included the hrl file in your code you can refer to the erlang record (or function) without any problem". Nope only you said this specifically. Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: i slightly changed my answer so that you may know where to put the -include() part in your OTP files.

Answer (score 3):

`rr` is a shell command. You cannot use it it compiled code.

http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/shell.html

Comment: Well that sucks... is there some other way to make life simpler?

Comment: I think there is, let me Google …

Comment: Theres gotta be someway. Erlang is a pretty mature language.

Comment: Sorry, I did not find a solution. I though you could use the `.erlang` start-up file, but it did not work.

Comment: Why not add a header file with that record definition in your source file before compilation ?

Comment: @MuzaayaJoshua Well if you could somehow show an example of that working that would be great but I'm still not sure that would somehow load the record. How would that work in the .erl file?

Answer (score 3):

If your intent is to read many record definitions in the shell, in order to facilitate the debug, you can write a file containing all needed include statements and simply invoke rr once in the shell.

in rec.hrl:

```
-include("include/bank.hrl").
-include("include/reply.hrl").
```

and in the in the shell

```
1> rr("rec.hrl").
[account,reply]
2>
```

I didn't find any way to execute this automatically, when starting the VM.

Answer (score 1):

When working on a project, you can gather all necessary includes and other command line arguments that you want to use for that particular project in a plain text file. After having made the plain text file, you can start your shell:

```
erl -args_file FileName
```

where FileName is the name of the plain text file. Note that **all command line arguments accepted by erl are allowed**. See also erl Flags in [the ERTS Reference Manual](http://erlang.org/doc/man/erl.html)